# XML with html tags via simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, html, xml

I have some XML files with plain texts including HTML tags. When I load them into a div with 'simplexml_load_file' the HTML tags loss. Is there any method to use HTML tags via XML?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: show example  of file content and result html

Answer (score 0):

The PHP is:

```
?php
$filename = 'xmls/impressum_'.$lang['LANGUAGE'].'.xml';
?>

<div>
<p><?php echo simplexml_load_file ($filename)->text; ?></p>
</div>
```

The XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
<text>Hopp Ferenc Kelet-Ázsiai Művészeti Múzeum<br/>H–1062 Budapest,   Andrássy út 103.<br/>Tel.: (36–1) 3228476, (36–1) 3211798<br/><br/><br/>Levélcím:<br/>H–1091 Budapest, Üllői út 33–37.<br/>Tel.: (36–1) 4565110<br/>E-mail: <a href="mailto:infoœhoppmuzeum.hu"><font color="#FB9E1B">info@hoppmuzeum.hu</font></a><br/>Website: <a href="http://www.hoppmuzeum.hu" target="_blank"><font color="#FB9E1B">www.hoppmuzeum.hu</font></a><br/><br/><br/>Fehér arany, mohamedán kék és hamvas őszibarack<br/>Korai kínai kerámiák a Hopp Ferenc Kelet-Ázsiai Művészeti Múzeum gyűjteményében<br/>I. kötet<br/><br/>Szerző: Fajcsák Györgyi<br/><br/>A szöveget gondozta: Bardi Terézia<br/><br/>Fordította: Chris Sullivan, Tóth Zsuzsanna<br/><br/>Fotók: Sulyok Miklós<br/><br/>DVD terv: Szörényi Beatrix<br/>DVD kivitelezés: <a href="http://www.netrix.hu"><font color="#FB9E1B">Netrix Kft.</font></a><br/><br/>Kiadja: Hopp Ferenc Kelet-Ázsiai Művészeti Múzeum, Budapest, 2007<br/><br/>Sorozatszerkesztő: Renner Zsuzsanna<br/>ISBN 978-963-87548-0-6ö (sorozat)<br/>ISBN 978-963-87548-1-3 (magyar nyelvű anyag)<br/>ISBN 978-963-87548-2-0ö (serie)<br/>ISBN 978-963-87548-3-7 (English text)<br/><br/>© Hopp Ferenc Kelet Ázsiai Művészeti Múzeum<br/>© Szöveg: Fajcsák Györgyi<br/><br/>Támogatóink:<br/><br/>Nemzeti Kulturális Alap<br/>Chiang Ching-kuo Alapítvány, Tajvan<br/>Iparművészeti Múzeum<br/>Oktatási és Kulturális Minisztérium<br/>Baktay Ervin Alapítvány a Keleti Művészetekért<br/>MVM Partner Energiakereskedelmi Zrt.</text>
<picture url="sponsors_hun.png"></picture>
</document>
```

Thank you!